# Heroku Py deployment error 'App not compatible with buildpack'

Tags: python, heroku, deployment

Other similar issues with answers have not resolved my issue. My deployment method is GitHub and I've not run into an issue with pushing to the repo, however, nothing seems to be able to run. I did set the build pack to Python in the settings of my Heroku app.

For reference, this is my repo I'm using for deployment: https://github.com/EhabJames/MC-Bot-Disc

Full Error:

```
App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
       More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: Have you searched about this? The most common issue is that you're missing a `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`, or that they're not in the root of your repository. Do you have those files? Where are they in your repository? What do they contain?

Comment: Turns out my 'requirements.txt' file had a capitalized "R" - renaming it resolved the error. Thanks!